# Apple watch text on label

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm having a problem with the (label) when a phrase such as "**I am 20 years old**" is truncated to **"I am ...**" and the remaining sentence does not appear. Like that appears on the line below the remaining sentence or something.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController,WCSessionDelegate {

@IBOutlet var Notification: WKInterfaceLabel!
var watchNotification = "ok"
let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
//@IBOutlet var lblNotification: WKInterfaceLabel!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    initSession()
    super.willActivate()
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject])

{

    let msg = message["NotificationSentforIphone"] as! String
     Notification.setText("notificat :\(msg)")
    //lblNotification.setText("Notification:\(msg)")

}
@IBAction func ActionSentNotificationforIphone()
{
    let msg = ["NotificationSentforWatch" : watchNotification]

    session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: {(replay) -> Void in }) { (error) -> Void in



    }

}
override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}

func initSession()

{

    session.delegate=self

    session.activateSession()



}



}
```

Comment: Can yo post your code?

Answer (score 0):

> **Lines** The maximum number of lines to allow for the label text. Text that does not fit on the specified number of lines is truncated.

All you have to do is

```
lblNotification.lines = 2;
```

Most of the time, 0 is as many as it needs to, but here was not specified if this rule applies.

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

**About the line property**

In iOS and watchOS developing, you must use the line property on labels, in UIKit, NS or watchKit.

> Lines property demonstrates the maximum number of lines which a label
>   can have, and the default value is 1, so your text won't be shown
>   correctly if you have more than one line.

**Assigning the Number of Lines**

You can assign the number of lines from the Attributes Inspector on Interface Builder in Xcode while you have selected the table, or just use this code programmatically:

**Swift**

```
lblNotification.lines = 3 // or 4 or anything else
```

**Objective-C**

```
lblNotification.lines = 3; // or 4 or anything else
```

**Versatile Number of Lines**

If you want the lines to be versatile and infinity, and to increase as your text grows, 0 is the best value to use on that property, so the code will be the following:

**Swift**

```
lblNotification.lines = 0 // versatile
```

**Objective-C**

```
lblNotification.lines = 0; // versatile
```

**Truncated Text**

If you use a value less than the whole lines of text, it will be truncated. For example, if you have a 4-line text and you set the property to 3, the forth line will be truncated.

And don't forget, you could always change the value of this property in the Attributes Inspector of the Interface Builder (IB) in Xcode.

**Conclusion**

1- Lines property demonstrates the maximum number of lines which a label can have, and the default value is 1.

2- You can assign the number of lines from the Attributes Inspector on Interface Builder in Xcode.

3- If you want the lines to be versatile and infinity, and to increase as your text grows, 0 is the best value to use on that property.

4- If you use a value less than the whole lines of text, it will be truncated.